# How can Ajax access to DOM element's id generated by iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, iteration

I have a `Book` model and a page that displays a list of books in my library.
To display all books I iterate over `@books = Book.all`, list the result inside a table and offer the user the opportunity to book or return a book.

```
<% @books.each_with_index do |book, index| %>
  <tr id="book-<%= book.isbn %>">
    <td class="title"> <%= book.title %> </td>
    <td class="author"> <%= book.author %> </td>
    <td>
      <div id="booking_form_<%= index + 1 %>">
        <% if current_user.booked?(book) %>
          <%= render 'book_selections/return_book' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render 'book_selections/book_book' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

For each book, the booking form's unique `id` is generated by the `index` of the iteration. 
I would like to use Ajax to offer to the user the opportunity to allow my web page to send requests asynchronously to the server without leaving the page.
Thus the user would see the result of submitting the form without the need for the user of refreshing the page of for the application to redirect back to the page. 
The problem is that I have no access to the form's `id` because the `index` variable of the iteration cannot be used in the `js.erb` file.
The code below does not work:

```
app/views/book_selections/create.js.erb

$("#booking_form_<%= index + 1 %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('book_selections/return_book')) %>");
$("#books_count").html('<%= current_user.books.count %>');
```

I am looking for a way to save the index variable and make it available in the `js.erb` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use Book `id` instead of `index` of the iteration.

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr id="book-<%= book.isbn %>">
    <td class="title"> <%= book.title %> </td>
    <td class="author"> <%= book.author %> </td>
    <td>
      <div id="booking_form_<%= book.id %>">
        <% if current_user.booked?(book) %>
          <%= render 'book_selections/return_book' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render 'book_selections/book_book' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In your AJAX call, pass the `boook.id` as an argument.

You can do the folowings:

```
# @book is the instance variable you would define in your controller action
# example: @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id]) 
# params[:id] is the book id you would have sent as an argument
$("#booking_form_<%= @book.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('book_selections/return_book')) %>");
```